# How can I transpose specific values in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the data as:

```
     z        V1
 1:  1        NA
 2:  1        NA
 3:  1        NA
 4:  1        NA
 5:  2  8.369040
 6:  2  7.471732
 7:  2 11.693667
 8:  2 19.904610
 9: 41 40.453627
10: 41 37.244842
11: 41 38.539745
12: 41 20.026698
13: 74 12.406808
14: 74 12.921079
15: 74 15.804546
16: 74 17.347516
.
.
.
```

What I want is this:

```
   z V1.1  V1.2  V1.3  V1.4
1: 1   NA    NA    NA    NA
2: 2 8.369 7.47  11.69  19.90
.
.
```

I want to have z values as columns but their corresponding z value should stay still.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do `dcast(df1, rowid(z) ~ paste("V1.", z), value.var = 'V1')`

Comment: It doesn't do what I want. I'll check the question link you provide, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it should be the other way `dcast(setDT(df1), z ~ paste0("V1.", rowid(z)), value.var = "V1")`

Comment: Solved! Thanks very much.